# Cognito SDK integrate with google authentication in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-cognito

I am using Amazon Cognito SDK for my PHP website authentication. now I want to add login with google button to my login and register forms.is it possible to use google authentication within Cognito SDK without using hosted UI?

I know it's okay to have it on hosted UI. but I have the forms on my own website.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: @AnkushJain yes dear.